# declaring events as field or property , what are differences?

Tags: asp.net, events, event-handling

I read in a blog ( not remembering now ) that it's recommended to use **property syntax** ( add , remove blocks ) when defining many events that just few of them are supposed to be handled in any time . in other conditions using **field syntax** is fine .

what is the reason for this ?

Comment: Where exactly is this recommended - can you post a link?

Comment: WHat do you mean by "property syntax" and "field syntax"? My guess is you mean the full event syntax with explicit add/remove blocks, vs field-like events... but you should really be clearer.

Comment: @JonSkeet : sorry , I updated the question . I'm new to events so I thought that maybe these terms are standard terms !

Comment: @reza: Nope. Please read http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet : thank you , I briefly read it . based on this article , selecting the syntax is based on how much thread safety is important to the application.I'm defining my events in a class library to be used with a website . I don't know if Thread safety is a matter in this condition ?

Comment: @reza: No, that's just *one aspect*. Basically it's as fundamental as "do you want the default behaviour provided by field-like events or not?"

Comment: @JonSkeet , yes all I want is a simple event system .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "property syntax" you mean overriding the add/remove i.e.

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
    add
    {
        ...
    }
    remove
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

then you would only do that if you wanted to change the behaviour of add/remove for that particular event i.e. what happens when you call `+=`/`-=` on your event.

For general  use of events, you would pretty much always use the field declaration i.e.

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
```